# Sending Special character in parameter in Case of Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

I am trying to send data via ajax to my controller action like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/cotroller/action",
    data: {  fieldsOfStudy: $('[name=fieldsOfStudy]').serialize()}
})
```

fieldsOfStudy are select boxes having some special chars like ","and ":" etc and when I got data on controllers action they are like  Design%2CInterior but this should be Design:Interior, this happens only when I uses serialize() method in case of normal fOrm submission it works perfectly. Can you guys please suggest me how can i achieve this.

Comment: `%2C` is simply a `:` (colon) which has been url-encoded. You just need to url-decode it.

Comment: did you mean that I have to decode at server side, can you please give me snapshot for this?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your HTML code, this could work:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/cotroller/action",
    data: $('[name=fieldsOfStudy]').serialize()
})
```

or if you have only one field with a the name "fieldsOfStudy":

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/cotroller/action",
    data: {  fieldsOfStudy: $('[name=fieldsOfStudy]').val() }
})
```

Comment: thanx for your effort but there are number of fields with same name.

Comment: The first idea should work anyway. I'm not sure how grails expects the HTTP parameter name of arrays though.

Comment: The problem with your code is, that you encode the names twice. It should be something like  "fieldsOfStudy=My+first+value&fieldsOfStudy=My+second+value" and I think it is "fieldsOfStudy=fieldsOfStudy%3DMy%2Bfirst%2Bvalue%26fieldsOfStudy%3DMy%2Bsecond%2Bvalue"

Comment: @Abdullah: first code snippet works fine with your requirement and at controller you can get the list of `fieldsOfStudy` using `params.list('fieldsOfStudy')`. Try this..,.